# FullCalendar - Month view : Different behavior for selecting date ranges (no click and drag)

Tags: range, fullcalendar, selection, drag

I wonder if there's an alternative way to select a range of dates in month view, **without** click + drag?

My idea would be:

- 1st. click: Sets start date.
- On `mousemove`, date ranges highlight (up to the date the mouse pointer is over).
- 2nd. click: Sets end date.

Should I do this triggering manually `dragstart` on `dayClick` callback? I cannot find a way on the docs to hook to events there. What I'm missing?

Somehow related but different behavior I want to add, is to "highlight" a range of dates (in the fiddle are 4 days), from the selected start date. I've tried calling the `select` method via `dayClick` callback, but if I invoke `select` method programatically, only the start and end date highlights (and I would like to highlight also the ones inbetween).

(See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xeezawaki/qrjpv7w5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something like the following would give you a starting point for clicking one date and then another to highlight the first, last and all cells between. Mouseover is set up in the viewRender to ensure the elements you want to attach to are in the DOM.

Looking at the docs the only dragstart I can see is the eventDragStart, this is no use since at this point you don't have an event yet.

```
var startDate, endDate

viewRender: function( view, element ) {
  $( ".fc-row .fc-bg .fc-day" ).mouseover(function() {
    if (startDate != null && endDate == null){
      var hoverDate = moment($(this).data("date"));
      bookingCalendarSelector.fullCalendar('select', startDate, hoverDate.add(1, 'd'));
    }
  });
},
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  if (startDate == null) {
      startDate = date;
      bookingCalendarSelector.fullCalendar('select', startDate);
  } else if (endDate == null) {
      endDate = date;
      bookingCalendarSelector.fullCalendar('select', startDate, endDate.add(1, 'd'));
  } else {
      startDate = endDate = null;
      bookingCalendarSelector.fullCalendar('unselect');
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ally_murray/2b7s3dj1/

Comment: Many thanks for your time and answer! I didn't thought of add mouseover listeners directly on `.fc-row .fc-bg .fc-day` ... 
Unfortunately I cannot take your idea as a base for my code :( Out of frustration, I decided to switch the library to `flatpickr`, which had this behavior implemented out-of-the-box.

Comment: Ah right no worries, thanks for still accepting the answer now you no longer need it.

Comment: Of course! I got answered with a correct solution anyway and you invested some time to answer it. Even if I no longer need it now, still had learnt an idea to tackle a problem of this kind :)